# What is the best way to do comet/long polling in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comet, long-polling

Either existing libraries or a discussion of how to implement it would be fine. I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't require thread blocking. I've found some solutions (like juggernaut and orbited) and was wondering what else was out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like cramp http://m.onkey.org/2010/1/7/introducing-cramp also I have had luck running a node.js server along-side the rails server to handle long-polling and web sockets.

Comment: Can you write more about using node.js with rails? How is it setup and how do rails and node.js "talk" to each other?

Comment: One way to do this would be to use Rails database session store. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378376/rails-shared-sessions-with-activerecord